# Splitting a column into rows in html

Tags: html, jsp, html-table

I have below table

```
 <table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Header1</th>
    <th scope="col">Header2</th>
    <th scope="col">Header3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Col 1,Col 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want the values "Col 1" and "Col 2" to be displayed into the two different rows(one containing "Col 1" and other containing "Col 2") under the "Header3" column. I have tried using "rowspan" as well but it is getting printed out of table.

Comment: How does this table gets printed ?

Comment: I mean the values "Col 1" and "Col 2" are getting shown(printed) out of the table.

Comment: I tried something like 

 <table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Header1</th>
    <th scope="col">Header2</th>
    <th scope="col">Header3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <tr>Col 1</tr>
    <tr>Col 2</tr>
  </tr>
</table>

Comment: How about this `<tr><th scope="row" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</th><td  rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td><td>Col 1</td> </tr><tr><td>Col 2</td></tr>` .Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/h1g89ntL/)

Comment: Thanks. Any specific reason you used <th> ?

Comment: No it was there in your code so i just use same ..:D .You can use `td` or `th` .

Comment: Oops my bad. Thanks it worked

Comment: @Swati. Can I do this without using <tr>?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221783/discussion-between-swati-and-anurag1804).

Answer (score -1):

```
This Code Can Help 

<html>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th scope="col">HEADER1</th>
<th scope="col">HEADER2</th>
<th colspan=2>HEADER3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>col1</td>
<td>col2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: "... in two different **rows** " not cells